# How to use Case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 SQL SELECT statements, how to use CASE statement and get a single SELECT statement.

My Query is:

```
-- Earned Points

SELECT CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) as 'Date' , p.PointsItemValue as 'Point Value', pi.PointsItemDesc
    FROM PointsTransaction p
    JOIN PointsTransactionType ptt ON ptt.PointsTransactionTypeID = p.PointsTransactionTypeID
    JOIN PointsItem pi ON pi.PointsItemID = p.PointsItemID
    JOIN Person pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN School s on s.SchoolID = p.SchoolID
    WHERE p.PersonID = @PersonID AND pe.SchoolID = @schoolid AND CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ThruDate and p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 1  and p.IsVoid = 0

-- Redeemed Points

SELECT CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) as 'Date' , p.PointsItemValue as 'Point Value', pi.PointsItemDesc
    FROM PointsTransaction p
    JOIN PointsTransactionType ptt ON ptt.PointsTransactionTypeID = p.PointsTransactionTypeID
    JOIN PointsItem pi ON pi.PointsItemID = p.PointsItemID
    JOIN Person pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN School s on s.SchoolID = p.SchoolID
    WHERE p.PersonID = @PersonID AND pe.SchoolID = @schoolid AND CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ThruDate and p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 2 and p.IsVoid = 0

-- Voided Points    

SELECT CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) as 'Date' , p.PointsItemValue as 'Point Value', pi.PointsItemDesc
    FROM PointsTransaction p
    JOIN PointsTransactionType ptt ON ptt.PointsTransactionTypeID = p.PointsTransactionTypeID
    JOIN PointsItem pi ON pi.PointsItemID = p.PointsItemID
    JOIN Person pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
    JOIN School s on s.SchoolID = p.SchoolID
    WHERE p.PersonID = @PersonID AND pe.SchoolID = @schoolid AND CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ThruDate and p.IsVoid = 1
```

Comment: Please tell us the difference between them and don't expect us to read and waste time understanding on our own.

Comment: @sagi - it took about 10 seconds looking at the queries to realize they are all identical except for a couple of predicates in the where clause.

Comment: Please give examples of input (source records, several of each kind) and also what the combined result should be.

Comment: @SeanLange Doesn't matter, people should always provide explanation. This is very general and looks like the OP didn't spend any effort on writing this, except copy paste. Think about it that way, if he'd change something very small outside the `WHERE` clause, u'll probably miss it, and will post a wrong answer.(Yes I know it's not the case)

Comment: It may be better for performance reasons to keep these queries separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    [Date] = cast(p.Transactiondt as date)
  , Earned_Points   = sum(case when p.IsVoid = 0 and p.PointsTransactionTypeid = 1 then p.PointsItemValue end)
  , Redeemed_Points = sum(case when p.IsVoid = 0 and p.PointsTransactionTypeid = 2 then p.PointsItemValue end)
  , Voided_Points   = sum(case when p.IsVoid = 1 then p.PointsItemValue end)
  , pi.PointsItemDesc
from PointsTransaction p
  inner join PointsTransactionType ptt
    on ptt.PointsTransactionTypeid = p.PointsTransactionTypeid
  inner join PointsItem pi
    on pi.PointsItemid = p.PointsItemid
  inner join Person pe
    on pe.Personid = p.Personid
  inner join School s
    on s.Schoolid = p.Schoolid  --<--shouldn't this be pe.Schoolid ? 
where p.Personid = @Personid
  and pe.Schoolid = @schoolid
  and cast(p.Transactiondt as date) between @FromDate and @ThruDate
group by 
    cast(p.Transactiondt as date)
  , pi.PointsItemDesc
```

Comment: Without knowing the data and relationships, solution involving `GROUP BY` is sketchy. I would **at least** include "PointsTransactionID" (if there is one) in the `GROUP BY` to ensure that the correct number of records is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As you thought you can do this with a case expression easily. Also, FWIW using a string as a column alias has been deprecated.

```
SELECT CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) as 'Date' 
    , p.PointsItemValue as 'Point Value'
    , pi.PointsItemDesc
    , case when p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 1  and p.IsVoid = 0 then 'Earned Points'
            when p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 2 and p.IsVoid = 0 then 'Redeemed Points'
            when p.IsVoid = 1 then 'Voided Points'
        end
FROM PointsTransaction p
JOIN PointsTransactionType ptt ON ptt.PointsTransactionTypeID = p.PointsTransactionTypeID
JOIN PointsItem pi ON pi.PointsItemID = p.PointsItemID
JOIN Person pe ON pe.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN School s on s.SchoolID = p.SchoolID
WHERE p.PersonID = @PersonID 
    AND pe.SchoolID = @schoolid 
    AND CAST(p.TransactionDT AS DATE) BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ThruDate 
    and 
    (
        p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 1  and p.IsVoid = 0
        OR
        p.PointsTransactionTypeID = 2 and p.IsVoid = 0
        OR
        p.IsVoid = 1
    )
```